# Get props value suggestion in custom react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a component named `TextName` which takes `name` props like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const TextName = props => {
  const { name } = props;
  return <p>Hello {name}</p>;
};

TextName.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.oneOf(['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
};

export default TextName;
```

I import this component to another component. That's working fine.
Is is possible to get suggestion with name props like this snapshot? [image]

Comment: Can you explain more what is "suggestion with name props"? It is not clear to me as what are you trying to achive.

Comment: You need to use typescript where you need to declare props interface. then you will get suggestion by using intelliSense feature of editor.

Comment: @Rahul Kumar, You get me and now I got you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prop types suggestions is not possible with javascript setup. Change it to typescript and use Proptypes with it to get the desired props suggestion.

## Adding `typescript` to a new project with create-react-app (cra):

### with `npm`

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

### with `yarn`

`yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`

## Adding `typescript` to an existing react project :

### 1. Install typescript related dependencies

`yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest --dev`

### 2. Changing file extensions

Change all the files that return `jsx` to `.tsx`. Files that doesn't return `jsx` should have `.ts` extension

### 3. Adding Prop types and State types

Consider the above code. To change it to have prop type suggestions we change it this way.

```
    interface TextNameProps {
        name: "X" | "Y" | "Z";
    }
    
    const TextName = (props: TextNameProps) => {
      const { name } = props;
      return <p>Hello {name}</p>;
    };
```

In the above code we have 2 changes,

1. Creating an interface of `TextNameProps`
2. Adding this to props of `TextName` Component

### 4. Updating package.json and tsconfig files

When you run the project with `npm start` or `yarn start` react automatically detects the use of tsx and adds `tsconfig`. If it prompts to add the file accept it to add the file.

With this you will see suggestions like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can add a default value to the "props" argument of your component like this:

```
const propsStructure = {
   content: null,
}  

const SomeComponent = (props = propsStructure) => {
  return <div>{props.content}</div>
}
```

Now you will get "content" as a suggestion every time you call the "SomeComponent" in any other component.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** have to use TypeScript as suggested above. However, it is a solution. Instead, if you are using regular JavaScript, you can use documentation tools like JSDoc. Code editors will understand and act upon your documentation and give you suggestions.

Here is an example:

```js
/**
 * Represents a book.
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} title - The title of the book.
 * @param {string} author - The author of the book.
 */
function Book(title, author) {
}
```

The code editor will understand that `title` and `author` are strings; it would not give you inside options but it will give you some hint.

It would also work if there are some object parameters like:

```js
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function(employee) {
    // ...
};
```

You can also add default values to it.